# Access VBA. Search data in a recordset from another data found in a recordset, all from SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table in Access that shows products and its associated codes. Each product should have a code, but sometimes users make a mistake and give the same code to two different products. I call this the "duplication mistake"

To that extent, everything is normal. The fields of the above mentioned table are:
Name, Tipus, IdProvider, Price, CodeBar. The only two which are important to us are Name and CodeBar.

To prevent duplication mistake results, but providing the opportunity to keep duplicated codes, I've added a button that warns user about this issue. So here is the code of that button.

```
Dim Magazine As Database
Dim Verification As Recordset
Dim CodProd As Recordset
Dim n As Integer
Dim way As String
Dim List As String
Dim SQL2 As String
Dim SQL As String
Dim CodProduct As String
Dim NameBarrasDuplicado As String

Set Magazine = CurrentDb

SQL = " SELECT Warehouse.CodeBar FROM Warehouse GROUP BY Warehouse.CodeBar HAVING (((Count(Warehouse.[CodeBar]))>1))"
Set Verification = Magazine.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset)

If (Verification.RecordCount > 0) Then
    SQL2 = "SELECT Warehouse.Name FROM Warehouse WHERE Warehouse.CodeBar = '" & Verification.Fields(0) & " ' "

    Set CodProd = Magazine.OpenRecordset(SQL2, dbOpenDynaset)
    CodProd.MoveFirst

    Do Until Verification.EOF
          Do Until CodProd.EOF
              CodProduct = CodProd.Fields(0) & ", " & CodProducto & ""
              MsgBox (CodProduct)
              CodProd.MoveNext
          Loop
          CodProd.MoveFirst
          List = List & ", " & Verification.Fields(0)
          Verification.MoveNext
    Loop

    MsgBox ("Warehouse duplicated products are: " & CodProduct & " for these Barcodes : " & List & ".")

Else
    MsgBox ("Everything OK, no duplicated codes found")
End If
```

End Sub

Unfortunately, the result of the before mentioned algorithm is this:
[image: Result of this algorithm in a MsgBox]

The results are wrong. Instead of showing the Names of the products that share the duplicated BarCode, it shows the same Names, with no relation about the barcodes. I wish to point that the duplicated barcodes are ok, they are the ones. But the program fails when it's about to show the product names that have these duplicated codes.

Anyone can give a clue about this? What is making the second recordset to only save two product's name instead of one?

Comment: From my perspective it has no sense to allow duplicates. Allowing duplicates in key fields is a source for problems. It is much better to put a code in the field and when leaving the field the system checks if the value is already in the DB and shows a message on that case. Also just leave MS-Access to show the standard error message when user try to insert a duplicate.

Comment: Additionally, there is no DDL to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Add the fields to your first query `Warehouse.Name` for example.   Cant really understand what is going in?

Comment: Also, it looks like you are not looping the 1st recordset in order to get the 2nd recordset.  `Verification`'s 11st record only seems to be used.